# Javascript: Setting variables in function declaration

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
    function toggleHiddenOps(dir, tour = false){
        // do stuff
    }
```

I noticed it was breaking in Chrome and IE (seems to work in FF 27). If I change the above to:

```
    function toggleHiddenOps(dir, tour){
        // do stuff
    }
```

It resolves the problem. Is there some issue with declaring variables like this in JS? Or perhaps my problem actually lies elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you wanting to assign a variable in the arguments, rather than in the function body itself?

Comment: To define a default value. This is possible in PHP.

Comment: It's possible to define defaults in JavaScript as well, but you have to do it in the function body (for most browsers, but I'm unsure as to why it's preferable to it the way you outline in your question).

Comment: That syntax [is coming in ECMAScript6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:parameter_default_values). At the moment, very few engines support it.

Comment: It's a case of writing more succinct code. I often use this syntax in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality exists only in FF for now. It [will be in ECMAScript6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aparameter_default_values), so expect it to start showing up in other engines over time.

Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari don't support that syntax in their latest versions.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2Fdefault_parameters

A good workaround for this is to use `arg= typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : defaultValue;`

For example:

```
function multiply(a, b) {
   b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ?  b : 1;
   return a*b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. Best answer, will accept in a minute when I am able. Seems like a shortcoming to me... as usual FF wins.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify default values in JS using PHP syntax.

To be fair, draft ECMAScript 6 specification allows to specify default argument value like in PHP, and this is even supported in Firefox 15+, but note that support of ES6 itself is mostly experimental and can theoretically be changed or removed at any point.

A future-proof/cross-browser way to check in JS if argument is not specified is following:

```
function toggleHiddenOps(dir, tour) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof tour) {
        tour = 'Some default value';
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I suspected. Thanks.

Comment: You can't *yet*. It's coming in ES6.

Comment: *"In JS, you can check if argument is not specified this way"* That doesn't check whether the argument is unspecified. It checks whether the argument's value is `undefined`. It may be that it's undefined because it was unspecified; alternately, it may be that it was specified, but `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You should probably be more specific and provide an alternative that does not have what you consider an issue.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: I don't consider it an issue. I'm just saying the text is incorrect. I'm not saying there's a problem with the code. Other than the completely unnecessary Yoda-speak, that's how I'd do it, too.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you are talking about passing a possibly uninitialized variable to a function, such function call would not make sense anyway (at least in most cases).

Comment: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments, '1')` is what is being suggested I believe. If you want to check if `specified` rather than just `undefined`

Comment: @MaratTanalin: No, of course I'm not. If you *really* want to know whether that argument was passed, `arguments.length` will tell you. (`arguments` being a pseudo-array created for every function call containing the *actual* arguments it was called with.) The check you're doing just checks for `undefined`, not whether the argument was passed, as I said originally. For supplying a default, I would use what you've put in the code, because `arguments` can be expensive on some engines. It's just the text saying what the code given does is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is illegal in javascript.

If you want a default exactly `false`:

```
function toggleHiddenOps(dir, tour){
   tour = tour === void(0) ? false : tour;
   // do stuff
}
```

If you only care if its falsey:

```
function toggleHiddenOps(dir, tour){
   // do stuff, tour equals undefined now if not passed 2nd param
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function don't support default paramter, a hack for it is:

```
function toggleHiddenOps(dir, tour){
    tour = typeof tour === 'undefined' ? 'default value' : tour
    console.log(dir)
    console.log(tour)
}
toggleHiddenOps('dir')
```